# Can I get some assistance with a Regex query for GA that I cant get to work?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm hoping someone can help me with a regex query.

I'm trying to set up a goal in GA there are multiple strings that can meet the requirement with one main section (being the book title) that can be swapped.

```
step1:/ebooks/best-practices-for-training-with-video
goal completion location: /ebooks/best-practices-for-training-with-video/?success=1
```

The book title can change but I want the query to pick up the goal completion regardless of the book title.

I thought I needed to do it like this:

```
step1:ebooks\/\w.+
goal completion location: ebooks\/\w.+\?success=1
```

But it isn't working as step 1 is picking up the success string too.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are forward slashes missing in the pattern before `ebooks`. Do you mean you want to capture `best-practices-for-training-with-video` before `/?success=1` ?

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird! I want to capture any of the options eg. ebooks/name - so in this case the name is best-practices-for-training-with-video

Comment: Like this with a capture group? https://regex101.com/r/3C6rlV/1 or https://regex101.com/r/rplwCm/1

Comment: The value in the previous patterns is in the first capture group.This will match only the part before the /?success=1 `[^\/]+(?=\/\?success=1)` https://regex101.com/r/kg4nND/1

Answer (score 0):

If your video URLs can only ever contain lowercase letters and hyphens then you should be able to use these patterns:

```
step 1: `^\/ebooks\/[a-z0-9-]+$`
goal  : `^\/ebooks\/[a-z0-9-]+\?success=1$`
```

The `^` means "start of line" and `$` means "end of line", so wrapping your pattern with these will mean it only matches if the entire line fits the pattern you specify. (That will stop your first regex matching because it only fits some, not all, of the success URL.)

If your video URLs can contain question marks and equals signs and digits, then this won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Bobulous the name can have letters or numbers e.g. top-10-training-practices but they wont contain question marks or symbols etc

Comment: I've edited my answer so that the patterns allow digits zero to nine within the video URLs.

Answer (score 0):

To get a match only, you could match 1 or more times any char except a forward slash `[^\/]+` and assert using a positive lookahead `(?=` that `\?success=1` is directly to the right.

```
[^\/]+(?=\/\?success=1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kg4nND/1)

Using a capture group, you might also use `([^\/]+)` capturing 1 or more chars except a forward slash.

```
step1:\/ebooks\/\w.+goal completion location: \/ebooks\/([^\/]+)\/\?success=1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rplwCm/1)